# Python: why the number should be string in if-statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I am new to Python and I was reading some examples about it. However, one example below

```
print "You enter a dark room with two doors.  Do you go through door #1 or door #2?"

door = raw_input("> ")

if door == "1":
    print "There's a giant bear here eating a cheese cake.  What do you do?"
    print "1. Take the cake."
    print "2. Scream at the bear."

    bear = raw_input("> ")

    if bear == "1":
        print "The bear eats your face off.  Good job!"
    elif bear == "2":
        print "The bear eats your legs off.  Good job!"
    else:
        print "Well, doing %s is probably better.  Bear runs away." % bear

elif door == "2":
    print "You stare into the endless abyss at Cthulhu's retina."
    print "1. Blueberries."
    print "2. Yellow jacket clothespins."
    print "3. Understanding revolvers yelling melodies."

    insanity = raw_input("> ")

    if insanity == "1" or insanity == "2":
        print "Your body survives powered by a mind of jello.  Good job!"
    else:
        print "The insanity rots your eyes into a pool of muck.  Good job!"

else:
    print "You stumble around and fall on a knife and die.  Good job!"
```

I was curious that why `if door == "1":` this one is double quoted rather than just a number one. I tried to remove double quote and the program would print `"You stumble around and fall on a knife and die.  Good job!"` if the input is one.

Comment: Because strings are not numbers, and `raw_input()` returns a string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `raw_input()` 'reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that'. Docs on the function [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

Therefore, your conditional statements check for values returned by `raw_input()` which are always strings.